# Ck editor Special charachter issue '&'

Tags: character-encoding, ckeditor, special-characters

I am using Ck Editor and i am getting wrong text.

For example if i am post the data like : "K & S" -> I will get only "K" Not posted data like  "K & S"

I have used below code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('PageDescription'
   );
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
        config.htmlEncodeOutput = false;
        config.entities = false;
    };

</script>
```

ANd for data pass : `CKEDITOR.instances.PageDescription.getData()`

Bu do not want to use : escape(CKEDITOR.instances.PageDescription.getData()) because i am using chinese languange purpose.

Please help me on this issue.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
CKEDITOR.config.entities_processNumerical = 'force';
```

Whether to convert all remaining characters not included in the ASCII character table to their relative decimal numeric representation of HTML entity. When set to force, it will convert all entities into this format. For example : 汉语."

docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.entities_processNumerical